# Liferay LDAP Authentication does not work properly

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.2 and I am trying to do LDAP Authentication. The LDAP Server is provided by another organization and I do not have access to any configuration, I just have credentials for a system account to look up the directory. When I try to log in Liferay with user credentials from the LDAP Server the authentication fails with the following error code:

```
13:54:05,738 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][LDAPAuth:341] Problem accessing LDAP server
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr:
DSID-0315270B, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'O=uni,C=de' remaining name 'ou=people,o=uni,c=de'
```

The same error that occurs when trying to log in with a user that does not exist in the LDAP directory. Nevertheless, the mapping still works. After trying to log in with valid user credentials there is an entry in the liferay database with the corresponding user data. Accessing Liferay is not possible though.

These are my settings in portal-ext.properties (Test LDAP connections returns success, connection settings are pseudonymised):

```
ldap.base.provider.url=ldaps://ldap.ldap-server
ldap.base.dn=ou=people,o=uni,c=de
ldap.security.principal=uid=prox,ou=prox,o=uni,c=de
ldap.security.credentials=secret

#auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false

ldap.auth.enabled=true
ldap.auth.required=true
ldap.auth.method=bind

ldap.import.enabled=false
ldap.import.on.startup=false
ldap.import.interval=10
ldap.export.enabled=false
ldap.export.group.enabled=false

ldap.auth.search.filter=(uid=@screen_name@)
ldap.import.user.search.filter=(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)

ldap.attrs.transformer.impl=com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.DefaultAttributesTransformer
ldap.user.mappings=screenName=cn\npassword=userPassword\nfirstName=givenNam\nlastName=sn\njobTitle=title\ngroup=groupMembership

users.email.address.required=false
users.email.address.auto.suffix=@no-emailaddress.com
users.email.address.generator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.DefaultEmailAddressGenerator
users.email.address.validator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.DefaultEmailAddressValidator

ldap.password.policy.enabled=false
ldap.import.user.password.enabled=true
ldap.import.user.password.autogenerated=false
ldap.import.user.password.default=test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. There were two issues:

1. I changed ldap.base.dn=ou=people,o=uni,c=de to ldap.base.dn=o=uni,c=de and
2. ldap.import.user.search.filter=(objectClass=inetOrgPerson) to ldap.import.user.search.filter=(objectClass=*)

Answer (score 0):

Check the FQDN on the LDAP side, including the prefixes (cn, ou, etc.), and ensure that it matches the directory configuration within Liferay.

You can try configuring it from the control panel it will be easier for you as it allows to check whether the connection is made or not. You can check the users are fetched or not and it doesnt even need a server restart.

Comment: Actually I used the control panel as well. I just used the properties file to share my settings. Regarding the authentication on the LDAP Server Side it seems to work correctly. The guys responsible for the LDAP Server checked the log files. I thought it could be a problem with the mapping since the LDAP Server doesn't provide mail and password as attributes. The password is still mapped into the databse, probably from the log in fields. The mail attribute is disabeld by users.email.address.required=false. Log in doesn't work though.